# Fastest way to calculate time periods weighted average in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
    timestamp                  parameter     value
    ---------------------------------------------------
    2015-09-04 10:00:00.000    par01          1
    2015-09-04 10:03:00.000    par02          2
    2015-09-04 10:06:00.000    par03          3
    2015-09-04 10:09:00.000    par04          4
    2015-09-04 10:12:00.000    par05          5
    2015-09-04 10:15:00.000    par06          6
    2015-09-04 10:18:00.000    par01          7
    2015-09-04 10:21:00.000    par02          8
    2015-09-04 10:24:00.000    par03          9
    2015-09-04 10:27:00.000    par04          10
```

I would like to calculate the weighted average every 15 minutes. The result must be like this:

```
    timestamp                  parameter     value
    ---------------------------------------------------
    2015-09-04 10:00:00.000    result1        3
    2015-09-04 10:15:00.000    result2        8
```

What's the fastest way? Is It possible avoiding loops?

Comment: case when minute-part between 0 and 14 when ... end

Comment: Which column keeps the weight ?

Comment: The weight is the difference between the current time row and the previous one in comparison a fixed time period.

Comment: which version of sql server ? This can be done easier on sql server 2012.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I've installed SQL Server 2012

Comment: @JosepBacardit changed my answer to include weighted average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the result you are requesting:

```
DECLARE @t table(timestamp datetime, parameter char(5),  value int)

INSERT @t values
('2015-09-04 10:00:00.000','par01',1),
('2015-09-04 10:03:00.000','par02',2),
('2015-09-04 10:06:00.000','par03',3),
('2015-09-04 10:09:00.000','par04',4),
('2015-09-04 10:12:00.000','par05',5),
('2015-09-04 10:15:00.000','par06',6),
('2015-09-04 10:18:00.000','par01',7),
('2015-09-04 10:21:00.000','par02',8),
('2015-09-04 10:24:00.000','par03',9),
('2015-09-04 10:27:00.000','par04',10)

SELECT
  dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0,timestamp)/15*15, 0) timestamp,
  'Result' + cast(row_number() over (order by datediff(minute, 0,timestamp)/15)
    as varchar(10)) parameter,
  avg(value) value
FROM @t
GROUP BY datediff(minute, 0,timestamp)/15
```

Result:

```
timestamp         parameter  value
2015-09-04 10:00  Result1    3
2015-09-04 10:15  Result2    8
```

EDIT here is a method to calculated weighted average. Been a learning experience for me:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT
    cast(coalesce(lead(timestamp)  over (order by timestamp), 
      dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0,timestamp)/15*15, '00:15'))
      - timestamp as float)*24*60/15*value x,
    dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0,timestamp)/15*15, 0) truncatedtime
FROM @t
)
SELECT
  sum(x) weighted_average,
  truncatedtime
FROM
  cte
GROUP BY
  truncatedtime
```

Comment: The result of the formula is the Average. I would like the time weighted average.

Comment: @JosepBacardit weighted average without a description of the weight is just plain average

Comment: I see a minor error in my calculation, going to try to fix it

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT  MIN(timestamp) as timestamp, 
        'result' + cast(count(*) over(order by min(timestamp)) as varchar(10)) as parameter,    
        AVG(value) as value
FROM tbl
GROUP BY CAST(timestamp as Date), 
         DATEPART(Hour, timestamp), 
         DATEPART(Minute, timestamp) / 15
```

[see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50327/1)

Comment: Would like to +1 because of the beauty of the simplicity of it, but since the query only groups on the minutes of each hour, it would give incorrect results when the timestamp is spread over multiple hours. Perhaps a bit unorthodox, but something like grouping on `datediff(Minute, timestamp, '20000101') / 15` ?

Comment: @Me.Name: Good catch!  the simplest solution I could think of is in my edited answer.

Comment: the syntax is still invalid. You can't use order by min(timestanp). A more simple *group by* can be found in my answer

Comment: The result of the formula is the Average. I would like the time weighted average.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk actually sqlfiddle seems to be o.k with the syntax, and the group by in your answer also is only by mod 15 of the minutes only...

Comment: @josep I'm sorry,  I've missed that part... will try to come up with a better answer tomorow.

Comment: the group by in my answer contains divide, not mod, there is a world of difference. Tested your fiddle on a 2008 which gave an errror. On a 2012 however it worked.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I see your point about the order by, about the error you got, that's strange, since the fiddle is supposed to be for 2008... I don't have an actual 2008 server to test on but I'll take your word for it. Anyway this is not what the OP is looking for since he wants a weighted average, not a "regular" average... Anyway, I think our answers are very similar, though yours is a bit better.

Comment: @ZoharPeled tried weighted average answer, I hope it works

Comment: @t-clausen.dk that's too much math for me at this early part of the century :-)... I've already upvoted your answer before, sorry I can't do it again :-)

Comment: I know you upvoted, thanks for that, just wanted to show you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    [Timestamp] datetime,
    Parameter VARCHAR(50),
    Value int
)

INSERT INTO #t1
VALUES ('2015-09-04 10:00:00.000', 'par01',1),
    ('2015-09-04 10:03:00.000', 'par02',2),
    ('2015-09-04 10:06:00.000', 'par03',3),
    ('2015-09-04 10:09:00.000', 'par04',4),
    ('2015-09-04 10:12:00.000', 'par05',5),
    ('2015-09-04 10:15:00.000', 'par06',6),
    ('2015-09-04 10:18:00.000', 'par01',7),
    ('2015-09-04 10:21:00.000', 'par02',8),
    ('2015-09-04 10:24:00.000', 'par03',9),
    ('2015-09-04 10:27:00.000', 'par04',10)


;WITH CTE
As
(
    SELECT
           DATEADD( minute, 
                    ( DATEDIFF(minute, CONVERT(char(8),[Timestamp],112), [Timestamp]) / 15 ) * 15,
                    CONVERT(char(8),[Timestamp],112) ) as Timestamp_truncated,
           [Timestamp],
           parameter,
           value
    FROM #t1
)
SELECT Timestamp_truncated AS [Timestamp], AVG(Value) as Value
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY Timestamp_truncated
```